# Flatten an array of dictionaries to one dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, functional-programming

I am having an array of dictionaries with `columnId` and `columnValue` as a pair. Now i need to flatten it as `columnId` as the key and `columnValue` as the value of it. How is it possible to do with swift higher order functions?

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [["columnId": 123, "columnValue": "sample text"], ["columnId": 124, "columnValue": 9977332]]

//The end result should be:   
flattenedDictionary: [String: Any] = ["123": "sample text", "124": 9977332]
```

Note: Result dictionary will be in the form of `[String: Any]`

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
func flatten(_ pairs: [[String: Any]]) -> [String: Any] {
    pairs.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) {
        if let id = $1["columnId"] as? Int, let value = $1["columnValue"] {
            $0["\(id)"] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps;

1. Convert your input array into a sequence of key-value pairs using `compactMap`
2. Convert the sequence back into a dictionary using `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [["columnId": 123, "columnValue": "sample text"], ["columnId": 124, "columnValue": 9977332]]

let tupleArray:[(String,Any)] = arrayOfDictionaries.compactMap { dict in
    guard let id = dict["columnId"], let value = dict["columnValue"] else {
        return nil
    }
    return ("\(id)",value)
}

let flattenedDictionary: [String: Any] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: tupleArray)
```

Note that this code will throw an exception if there are duplicate keys. You should either take steps to ensure the `columnId` values are unique or use `Dictionary(keysAndValues:, uniquingKeysWith:)` to resolve id clashes.